# Не работает добавление ADO.NET EDM

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, entity-framework, ado.net

Понадобилось подключить БД MySQL к приложению WinForms посредством EF (ранее всегда работал с MSSQL).

Установил MySQL, создал БД, начал подключать (по принципу Database First), как описано, например, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031269/enable-entity-framework-6-for-mysql-c-in-winforms-of-microsoft-visual-studio).

Однако на этапе добавления модели ADO.NET возникла проблема: после шага "Выбор подключения к данным":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

окно закрывается, и далее ничего не происходит.

Вот мой `App.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="cashbox.Properties.Settings.goodsConnectionString" connectionString="user id=admin;password=admin;persistsecurityinfo=True;server=localhost;database=goods" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <!--<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>-->
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.9.0" newVersion="6.9.9.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data></configuration>
```

Если раскомментировать дефолтный тег `entityFramework` и закомментировать нынешний, попытка добавления модели ожидаемо приведёт к ошибке (при исходных условиях окно на этом моменте уже закроется).

Вроде, всё делаю по инструкции. Единственное, у меня vs2015 и .NET 4.5.2, а в ответе по ссылке выше инструкция для vs2013 и .NET 4.5.1 - но я сильно сомневаюсь, что в данном случае это критично.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: а коннект точно есть по этой строке?

Comment: @Anatol При создании соединения проверку проходит

Comment: смею предположить что проблема в использовании [tag:mysql] так как на [tag:mssql] все работает. подобная ситуация всплывала вот в этом [вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/573738/179270), а почему бы не воспользоваться подходом *code first* с ним вроде все работает

Comment: Раньше пользовался моделями с MySQL, местами это то еще шаманство, вплоть до того, что оно выше ef4 не хотело делать модели по неизвестным причинам (известным, но, порой даже с гуглом проблемы их найти) или не видело dll или еще что. Проще самому эту модель описать...

Comment: Мне просто непонятно: делаю, вроде, то же, что и все - но у всех работает, а у меня нет. Значит, что-то делаю не так. Оно же не может рандомно работать / не работать